# ¿como obtener el ultimo id insertado en JSF y Primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un problema en mostrar el ultimo código insertado y mostrarlo en mi aplicativo web como se muestra en la imagen cuando presiono el botón nuevo. Me muestra otra ventana  y donde dice código me tiene que mostrar `P007` pero  me muestra 'P0061'. Les dejo el código si me pueden ayudar muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Model

private String idprueba;
 private String nombre;

```
public String getIdprueba() {
    return idprueba;
}

public void setIdprueba(String idprueba) {
    this.idprueba = idprueba;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
```

En el DAO

public Prueba obtenerUltimoRegistro() throws Exception{
        ResultSet rs;
         Prueba prueba=null;
        try{

```
        this.Conectar();
       PreparedStatement st=this.getCn().prepareCall("SELECT Max(idprueba) as idprueba FROM pruebas");
        rs=st.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()){
           prueba=new Prueba();
           prueba.setIdprueba(rs.getString("idprueba"));

       }

    }catch(Exception e){
       // this.getCn().rollback();
        throw e;
    }finally{
        this.Cerrar();
    }
 return prueba;
}
```

En el Bean

```
public void numeracionPrueba()throws Exception{
       PruebaDao dao=new PruebaDao();;
       try{
           this.prueba=dao.obtenerUltimoRegistro();
           this.idprueba=this.prueba.getIdprueba()+1;

       }catch(Exception e){
           throw  e;
       }

   }
```

En XHTML

```
 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{pruebaBean.listar('F')}" />     
      <p:growl id="msj" autoUpdate="true" />
            <h:form id="frm">

                <p:commandButton value="Nuevo" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').show();" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.setAccion('Registrar')}"  onclick="#{pruebaBean.numeracionPrueba()}" update=":dlgDatos"/>
                <p:dataTable id="data" value="#{pruebaBean.lstPrueba}" var="prueba">
                    <p:column headerText="Codigo">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{prueba.idprueba}"/>
                   </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="descripcion">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{prueba.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>   


                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
      <p:dialog header="Registro de ......" widgetVar="wdlgDatos" id="dlgDatos">

           <h:form>
         <p:panelGrid columns="2">

         <p:outputLabel  value="codigo" />
         <p:outputLabel  value="#{pruebaBean.idprueba}"/>

           <p:outputLabel  value="des" />
           <p:inputText  value="#{pruebaBean.prueba.nombre}"/>


        <p:commandButton value="#{pruebaBean.accion}" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.operar()}" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();" update=":frm:data"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();"/>

        </p:panelGrid>           

        </h:form>
```

Comment: El método `void numeros()` del bean no devuelve ningún valor, por ello `value="#{pruebaBean.numeros()}"` no te da ningún resultado. Haz que `#{pruebaBean.numeros()}` retorne el siguiente código.

Comment: Podrías poner el código completo de tu tabla de la vista probablemente falte un update o el ajax o el selected retorne null.

Comment: Exactamente que Id necesitas?! La secuencia que sigue, o la ultima insertada en la tabla!?

Answer (score 1):

Es algo muy sencillo. Ordenas de forma descendente por código y limitas los resultados a uno. De esta manera, siempre obtendrás el último código insertado.

```
String sql = "SELECT p.codigo FROM Producto p ORDER BY p.codigo DESC";
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery(sql, String.class);
query.setMaxResults(1);
// cuidado, lanza NoResultException si no hay resultados
String lastCode = query.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si en el debug puedes observar el nuevo valor asignado. Échale un ojo al atributo update del action o botón que te abre el diálogo, panelgrid o lo que sea dale un id y refrescalo desde el action(atributo update) tal que así update =":idDelElemento"

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente de tu lógica para obtener el siguiente Id, no actualices directamente el diálogo e incluye un contenedor como por ejemplo `outputpanel`:

```
<p:dialog header="Registro de ......" widgetVar="wdlgDatos" id="dlgDatos">

      <h:form id="formDialog">

        <p:outputPanel id="output">

           <p:panelGrid columns="2">

               <p:outputLabel  value="codigo" />
               <p:outputLabel  value="#{pruebaBean.idprueba}"/>

               <p:outputLabel  value="des" />
               <p:inputText  value="#{pruebaBean.prueba.nombre}"/>


               <p:commandButton value="#{pruebaBean.accion}" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.operar()}" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();" update=":frm:data"/>
               <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();"/>

            </p:panelGrid>           

        </p:outputPanel>

    </h:form>
```

Y actualízalo en el commandButton con algo como lo siguiente:

`update=`**":formDialog:output"**

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ponle un id a tu form que esta dentro del dialog: **id="idFormRegistro"**

```
<p:dialog header="Registro de ......" widgetVar="wdlgDatos" id="dlgDatos">

           <h:form id="idFormRegistro">
         <p:panelGrid columns="2">

         <p:outputLabel  value="codigo" />
         <p:outputLabel  value="#{pruebaBean.idprueba}"/>

           <p:outputLabel  value="des" />
           <p:inputText  value="#{pruebaBean.prueba.nombre}"/>


        <p:commandButton value="#{pruebaBean.accion}" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.operar()}" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();" update=":frm:data"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();"/>

        </p:panelGrid>           

        </h:form>
```

y en tu botón nuevo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<p:commandButton value="Nuevo" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').show()" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.setAccion('Registrar')}"  onclick="#{pruebaBean.numeracionPrueba()}" update=":idFormRegistro"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en tu XHTML, debes hacerle update al dialog pero al form colocale un id al form del dialog así `<h:form id="formDialog">` y en el botón que manda a llamar al dialog agregar en el update el id del form **formDialog** `<p:commandButton value="Nuevo" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').show();" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.setAccion('Registrar')}"  onclick="#{pruebaBean.numeracionPrueba()}" update=":formDialog"/>`

```
 <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{pruebaBean.listar('F')}" />     
      <p:growl id="msj" autoUpdate="true" />
            <h:form id="frm">

                <p:commandButton value="Nuevo" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').show();" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.setAccion('Registrar')}"  onclick="#{pruebaBean.numeracionPrueba()}" update=":formDialog"/>
                <p:dataTable id="data" value="#{pruebaBean.lstPrueba}" var="prueba">
                    <p:column headerText="Codigo">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{prueba.idprueba}"/>
                   </p:column>  

            <p:column headerText="descripcion">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{prueba.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>   


                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
      <p:dialog header="Registro de ......" widgetVar="wdlgDatos" id="dlgDatos">

           <h:form id="formDialog">
         <p:panelGrid columns="2">

         <p:outputLabel  value="codigo" />
         <p:outputLabel  value="#{pruebaBean.idprueba}"/>

           <p:outputLabel  value="des" />
           <p:inputText  value="#{pruebaBean.prueba.nombre}"/>


        <p:commandButton value="#{pruebaBean.accion}" actionListener="#{pruebaBean.operar()}" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();" update=":frm:data"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" immediate="true" oncomplete="PF('wdlgDatos').hide();"/>

        </p:panelGrid>           

        </h:form>**texto en negrita**
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás concatenando a un String (idprueba) otro String (1) en el siguiente código

```
this.idprueba=this.prueba.getIdprueba()+1;
```

Dado en en idprueba se están almacenando valores de texto tales como:

- P001
- P002
- P003
- ...

Debieras extraer la parte entera de ese código y tratarlo como un número para poder incrementar en una unidad.